# Using GradientTape to compute gradients of predictions with respect to some tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement WGAN with GP in TensorFlow 2.0. To calculate the gradient penalty it requires you to calculate the gradients of the predictions with respect to input images.

Now, to make it a bit more tractable, instead of computing the gradients of the predictions with respect to all the input images, it computes interpolated data points along the lines of original and fake data points and uses these as the inputs.

To implement this, I am first developing the `compute_gradients` function which would take some predictions and return the gradients of those with respect to some input images. First, I thought of doing this with `tf.keras.backend.gradients` but it won't work in eager mode. So, I am trying to do this now using `GradientTape`.

Here's the code I am using to test things out:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Comes from Generative Deep Learning by David Foster
class RandomWeightedAverage(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    """Provides a (random) weighted average between real and generated image samples"""
    def call(self, inputs):
        alpha = K.random_uniform((self.batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])

# Dummy critic
def make_critic():
    critic = Sequential()
    inputShape = (28, 28, 1)

    critic.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same", strides=(2, 2),
        input_shape=inputShape))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    critic.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding="same", strides=(2, 2)))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    critic.add(Flatten())
    critic.add(Dense(512))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    critic.add(Dropout(0.3))
    critic.add(Dense(1))

    return critic

# Gather dataset
((X_train, _), (X_test, _)) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)

# Note that I am using test images as fake images for testing purposes
interpolated_img = RandomWeightedAverage(32)([X_train[0:32].astype("float"), X_test[32:64].astype("float")])

# Compute gradients of the predictions with respect to the interpolated images
critic = make_critic()
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = critic(interpolated_img)
gradients = tape.gradient(y_pred, interpolated_img)
```

The gradients are coming to be `None`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you check the value of interpolated_img? Is it all 0?

Comment: Is it a type or you are actually calling `tape.gradient` outside the context manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gradients of predictions with respect to some tensors ... Am I missing something here?

Yes. You need a `tape.watch(interpolated_img)`:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(interpolated_img)
    y_pred = critic(interpolated_img)
```

`GradientTape` needs to store the intermediate values of the forward pass to calculate the gradients. Usually, you want gradients WRT variables. So it doesn't keep the trace of calculations starting from tensors, probably to save memory.

If you want a gradient WRT a tensor, you need to explicitly tell the `tape`.